# Which PHP function uses such hash algorithm?

Tags: php, c, hash, php-internals

```
   1. static inline ulong zend_inline_hash_func(char *arKey, uint nKeyLength)
   2. {
   3.     register ulong hash = 5381;
   4.  
   5.     /* variant with the hash unrolled eight times */
   6.     for (; nKeyLength >= 8; nKeyLength -= 8) {
   7.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
   8.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
   9.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
  10.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
  11.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
  12.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
  13.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
  14.         hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++;
  15.     }
  16.     switch (nKeyLength) {
  17.         case 7: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; /* fallthrough... */
  18.         case 6: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; /* fallthrough... */
  19.         case 5: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; /* fallthrough... */
  20.         case 4: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; /* fallthrough... */
  21.         case 3: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; /* fallthrough... */
  22.         case 2: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; /* fallthrough... */
  23.         case 1: hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + *arKey++; break;
  24.         case 0: break;
  25. EMPTY_SWITCH_DEFAULT_CASE()
  26.     }
  27.     return hash;
  28. }
```

Answer (score 4):

All the hash tables use that hashing algorithm; hash tables in PHP are used, for instance, to implement arrays and symbol tables, among many other things.

The algorithm, as pointed in the [header](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_hash.h#228) is DJBX33A (Daniel J. Bernstein, Times 33 with Addition).

Comment: So it's only used internally by PHP,without such an api for PHP users?

Comment: I was going to answer with this too, but wasn't sure and got lost looking for sources. Looks like you confirmed it, +1

Comment: @ajx As far as I know there's no API for user-land.

Comment: @ajx It's easily implemented in PHP: 

        $key = "string to hash";
        $hash = 5381;

        for ($len = strlen($key), $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $hash = $hash * 33 + ord($key[$i]);
        }

Comment: @Artefacto, Why is this algorithm chosen instead of the one Java uses  `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link to see where this function is used:
http://lxr.php.net/search?q=+zend_inline_hash_func&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=PHP_5_4

looks like there are 3 php extensions (including standard) where this function is used.